# How do I put a pointer to an NSString pointer into a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsstring, nsdictionary

I would like to put a pointer to an NSString pointer into an NSDictionary, and naturally, get it back out again. But I can't figure out the syntax.

I think is is something like

```
NSString* myString = @"Hi";
NSString**myStringPointer = myString;

NSDictionary* dictionary = @{@"pointer":myStringPointer};
```

But that is clearly not correct.

I am trying to change what string an NSString points to inside a selector.

```
-(void) updateString:(NSString*) aString {
  aString = @"Hello World";   //
}

-(void) testUpdateString {
  NSString *textString = @"TEST";
  [self updateString:testString];
  // testString still is @"TEST";
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you want to do it. You might try NSValue.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't put pointers to pointers to objects in an NSDictionary.  Well, you can if you wrap them in NSValue or NSData, but why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only put (pointers to) things that inherit from `NSObject` in an NSDictionary; a pointer to (a pointer to) an `NSString` isn't such an object.  You can wrap it in an [`NSValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store it in a dictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"pointer": [NSValue valueWithPointer:myStringPointer], };
```

While it's worth being aware of the general idea of wrapping things that couldn't otherwise be put into an `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, etc., in `NSValue` for this purpose, I can't think of a good reason to store an `NSString **` in an `NSDictionary`, so it might be better to look at why you're trying to do that and whether there's a better way to achieve your larger goal.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a dictionary here, you can pass the object by reference to the updating
method:

```
-(void) updateString:(NSString **) aString {
    *aString = @"Hello World";
}

-(void) testUpdateString {
    NSString *testString = @"TEST";
    [self updateString:&testString];
}
```

(If you are curious what actually happens behind the scenes, look up
`__autoreleasing` in the ["Transitioning to ARC Release Notes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).)